# Is there a way to reconstruct a .git directory for a submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project with a submodule, and I want to be able to reconstruct the `.git` directory of the submodule, as if the submodule had been cloned.

In more detail, say I have a submodule `subproject` in a git project `superproject`, and I have already done:

```
git clone git://url.of.superproject
cd superproject
git submodule update --init
```

`subproject` does not have its own `.git` directory, but a `.git` file, pointing to the directory `../.git/modules/subproject`. I really need the real `.git` directory for `subproject`, because the tool I am using (Python's pip) insists on copying the `subproject` directory to an arbitrary location in order to work on it, and the work it will do includes running git commands.

Is there any way of reconstructing the `subproject/.git` directory as if it had been cloned?  I can't just copy the `.git/modules/subproject` directory because it contains relative links to other parts of the `superproject/.git` directory.

Comment: Is there some relative link besides the `core.worktree` setting?  If your subprojects aren't further nested you should be able to just  `cd subproject; git=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); rm .git && mv "$git" .git && git config --unset core.worktree`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I guess relative links must be fairly common -  trying your recipe on a real example https://github.com/MacPython/cython-wheels, subproject `Cython` gives me a broken submodule `Could not chdir to '../../../Cython`.

Comment: Hunh. `git --work-tree=. config --unset core.worktree`, fixes that.

Comment: What effect do you get when the submodule has a submodule?  When I add a `http://github.com/matthew-brett/multibuild` submodule to the `Cython` submodule, and run your commands above, then `git log`  in the `multibuild` directory gives `fatal: Not a git repository: ../../.git/modules/Cython/modules/multibuild`

Comment: If you've got them further nested you have to unwind them depth-first.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question - `git clone subproject` will build the `.git` directory:

```
git clone --recursive subproject subproject-copy
```

Now `subproject-copy/.git` is a full git directory.

Here's a bash function to do this in a more general way (reconstructing the `origin` remote correctly, etc):

```
function fill_submodule {
    # Restores .git directory to submodule, if necessary
    local repo_dir="$1"
    [ -z "$repo_dir" ] && echo "repo_dir not defined" && exit 1
    local git_loc="$repo_dir/.git"
    # For ordinary submodule, .git is a file.
    [ -d "$git_loc" ] && return
    # Need to recreate .git directory for submodule
    local origin_url=$(cd "$repo_dir" && git config --get remote.origin.url)
    local repo_copy="$repo_dir-$RANDOM"
    git clone --recursive "$repo_dir" "$repo_copy"
    rm -rf "$repo_dir"
    mv "$repo_copy" "$repo_dir"
    (cd "$repo_dir" && git remote set-url origin $origin_url)
}
```

Use with:

```
fill_submodule subproject
```